# Check if a string starts with a possible number of strings in C#?

Tags: c#, string, linq

How can I most efficiently check to see if an input string starts with a string that belongs in a list of strings?

For example `possiblePrefixes` = "1234", "1235", "1236". If `input` = "1235av2425" should return true. If `input` = "1237352ko" should return false.

Comment: Be careful with terms like "most efficiently". There are many ways of doing this, of various complexity (LINQ, regexes, *compiled* regexes, *source-generated* regexes, manual checks, manual checks optimized with SSE intrinsics...) Unless you've established this operation is a bottleneck, though, the simplest and most readable approach with LINQ (as given in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74888078/4137916)) is a good start and probably all you need.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `Any` for this. the concept here is you need to check whether there is any item in the list which is the prefix for the given string.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "1234", "1235", "1236" };
string input = "1237352ko";

var exisits = list.Any(x => input.StartsWith(x)); //returns false
```

when `string input = "1235av2425";` it will return `true`

Answer (score 1):

An efficient datastructure for this type of search would be a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (aka "Trie").

For your example data such a tree might look something like this:

```
123
|-4
|-5
|-6
```

This could allow a lookup time that is independent of the number of prefixes you want to check against.

But as far as I know there are no builtin types for this, so you would either need to find a library, or implement it yourself.

Comment: Yes, in case of many strings to be looked for Aho Corasick algorithm (or its modification for just prefixes) is a typical choice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `Any` and `StartsWith` will be the best in most cases. Looking for an optimized solution will only be necessary if you have a long list of possible prefixes and/or a long list of texts to check against the same prefixes.

In that case, using a pre-compiled regular expression built once from the list of possible prefixes and then re-used for multiple checks might be a little faster.

```
// Build regular expression once
string[] possiblePrefixes = new string[] { "1234", "1235", "1236" };
var escaped = possiblePrefixes.Select(p => Regex.Escape(p)); 
string pattern = "^(" + string.Join("|", escaped) + ").*";
Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

// Now use it multiple times
string input = "1235av2425";
bool result = regEx.IsMatch(input);
```

Comment: This should probably be `string pattern = "^(" + string.Join("|", escaped) + ").*";`

Comment: Note that using the static `Regex.IsMatch` method can beat out compiling a regex, depending on the complexity and how often you match. Unfortunately it's not a given that compiling is always the best thing to do just because the regex will be used many times, as the "many" may need to be many many indeed.

Comment: In .NET 7 there is also support for regex source generators. They will basically "compile" the regex during compilation of your source code, avoiding runtime cost of `RegexOptions.Compiled`.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the 2 solutions

**Solution # 1 (using Lambda Expression)**

```
List<string> possiblePrefixes = new List<string>() { "1234", "1235", "1236" };
string input = "1235av2425";
var result = possiblePrefixes.Any(x => input.StartsWith(x));
Console.WriteLine(result); //returns True
```

**Solution # 2 (using SQL)**

```
List<string> possiblePrefixes = new List<string>() { "1234", "1235", "1236" };
string input = "1235av2425";
var result = (from val in possiblePrefixes
             where input.StartsWith(val)
             select val).Any();
Console.WriteLine(result); //returns True
```